# event.preventDefault on child component which is calling parent function - React Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am not explaining my entire code structure. Here is my current situation. I have a method added to child component inside my parent component :

```
<TableRow obj={object} key={i} delteMethod={that.deleteRow} />
```

and my child component is defined like the below :

```
<a href="#" onClick={this.props.delteMethod.bind(this, this.props.obj.id)}>Delete</a>
```

This is my deleteRow() function in the parent component :

```
deleteRow(deleteid) {
      var that = this;
      deleteItem(deleteid).then(function(data){
        that.loadData();
      });
    }
```

This works. I am able to get the obj.id back in my parent component and I am doing rest of the tasks. What I want to do is, I want to add an event.preventDefault() function to the 'Delete' button click (the child component button which I said already working fine). How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define a function in your child component that will receive `event` and call your parent's function from `props`. Here is an example code for your child component:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onDeleteClick = this.onDeleteClick.bind(this);
}
onDeleteClick(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.props.delteMethod(this.props.obj.id);
}
render() {
    return (<a href="#" onClick={this.onDeleteClick}>Delete</a>);
}
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

you can have a click handler function in your component class like this

```
clickHandler = (e) => {
  this.props.delteMethod(this.props.obj.id);
  e.preventDefault();
}
```

and on the button you can have it like

```
<a href="#" onClick={this.clickHandler}>Delete</a>
```